# Error in the execution of a video in ubuntu

Tags: video

in Ubuntu, I downloaded a video, with the format `avi`, and when I open the file video, it gets an error, and it doesn't execute.

The error is, why it doesn't define the flux type.
[image]
What is this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`?

Comment: Please include *exact* error message in your question.

Comment: What video player are you using?  Have you tried any others, such as VLC or Xine?

Comment: I am using the default video player.

Comment: I downloaded the VLC and Xine, and when, open the video, don't run. It is loading, forever.